# unpack war to a directory using jar command.is that possible?

Tags: linux, command-line, jar

I've search online a way to unpack a war file from a location to a different one, and so far nothing satisfactory.
i use this command

```
jar -xvf mysite.war -C /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mysite/
```

it's not working.this :

```
jar -xvf mysite.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mysite/
```

is not throwing any error but still not working any idea?

Comment: I know that jar files are actualy zip files. Aren't jar file zip too?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079693/how-do-you-extract-a-jar-in-a-unix-filesystem-with-a-single-command-and-specify-i . Try unzip as one of the answers states.

Comment: @Aif They are, according to your first statement :) Just joking

Answer (score 10):

Found the [blog post at mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/java/the-java-archive-tool-jar-examples/)

As stated there: *"...jar does doesn’t has option to extract files to another folder directly..."* So what you need to do is change to the directory you want to extract to, and then refer the jar-file from there

```
mkdir newdir
cd newdir
jar -xvf /workspace/test/classes/test.jar
```

This will do the trick for you on Windows as well, since unzip is not available there by default.

Answer (score 5):

A `war` file is a zipped archive. Perhaps using `unzip` will work.