# Need help accessing data file in Jar File

Tags: java, eclipse, audio

I am having trouble reading a file that is in an exported jar file I had exported from my Eclipse project. I would like to acesss this same file when either running my application on the command line, or when running the same application within Eclipse and have it access the same file via the source hierarchy from within Eclipse (i.e not via the Jar File).

In my Java project, I have a folder called: SoundDir, and within it a sound file called: sonar-beep.wav .  This is the file I am having trouble accessing.

Here is the line of code I am trying to use to access the sound file:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("SoundDir/sonar-beep.wav");
```

When I run my program in the Eclipse Debugger, input keeps coming back as Null.  I assume it is not finding the file.

Any ideas on what is wrong?

Now, if this did work, I would want to use the inputStream as an argument to the Java SoundPlayer to play the music in this data file.  Can I supply "input" directly as the parameter, or do I need a BufferedReader or some other object on top of it?

```
AudioInputStream audioIn1= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(input);
```

Would appreciate any help on this!  New to all these classLoader issues.

Thanks.

---

Ok, now that this is solved.  See solution below from Robert, having same issue with image files.  I want my program to be able to locate them, whether the application is running within Eclipse, or on the command line.

Here is the code:
ImageIcon imageIcon= new ImageIcon(getImageURL("/ImageAirplanes/AirplaneRtoL.png"));

And here is the method getImageURL:

```
public URL getImageURL(String imageFilename) {
    URL aURL= null;

    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

    aURL= cl.getResource(imageFilename);

     return aURL;
}
```

I keep getting a null value for aURL when running the program within Eclipse.
And I do have the parent directory of ImageAirplanes (which is "Resources"), added to the Java Build Path for my project.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: It's important to know the file structure of your JAR. If you unpack it, is SoundDir at the root? In that case you need `/SoundDir/sonar-beep.wav` - noting the leading slash. Without the slash, the resource is loaded relative to the class returned by `getClass()` (i.e. the same package)

Comment: @Roberto: make that an answer, as that seems the solution. Also mind, that the path name must be case-sensitive (in contrast to the File path under Windows).

Comment: Hi Robert, SoundDir is at the root.  It is at the top level of my Project.  It is not under any package.  However, right now I am trying to get the code to work when running my program from within Eclipse.  And I still get a null back.  It is throws a Null Pointer Exception.  I've tried placing a leading slash on front of SoundDir, and without, and in each case it throws a Null pointer Exception.

Comment: In that case it could possibly be because the directory is not on the build path. Turn SoundDir into a Source Folder (Project -> Properties -> Java -> Build Path -> Source Folders -> Add Folder). Then change "/SoundDir/sonar-beep.wav" to just "/sonar-beep.wav"

Comment: Hi Roberto, that worked!  Thanks!  But, have another question as a result of this.  The sound files that I was trying to access are stored in Folders in my Project in Eclipse.  When I exported my project as a Jar File (so I can run the program on the command line), I see the sound files are in the top level of Jar File.  They are not contained in any folder.  The Folder that I was storing them in, within my Eclipse project, was not created within the Exported Jar File.  Would really prefer that their containing Folder was present in the Exported Jar File.  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Roberto: Hi Roberto, I am having the same issue with my Image Files.  I edited my original post to reflect this.  I posted the code.  Could you review it to see what is wrong?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Where is your SoundDir directory located in the JAR file? Try [unpacking the JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1079803/2347458) and checking if you are not sure.

If your SoundDir directory is located in the immediately inside the JAR'd directory, then it is relative to the JAR root directory, and you need to use `/SoundDir/sonar-beep.wav` - note the leading slash. This makes the path **absolute**, or **relative to root**

Without that slash, you are specifying a **relative path**, which is **relative to the classloader** - loading a resource that is contained in the same package as the class returned by `getClass()`.

To understand more deeply, it is helpful to understand [File System paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/path.html)

Comment: Hi Robert, see my comment above.  Right now trying to get the instruction above to work within Eclipse (i.e. it is not accessing a Jar file).  Am I doing this the right way?  Getting Null Pointer exceptions.

Comment: Hi Robert, your suggestion worked.  But have question about how to get sound files created within a directory in exported Jar file from Eclipse.  Their parenting directory is now gone from the exported Jar file.  See my comment above.  Thanks for the help with this!

Comment: The simplest solution to this is to create a sub-package. I'd suggest renaming the existing `SoundDir` **source folder** to `resources`, and creating a package **inside** `resources` called `SoundDir`. Make sure to update your path to `/SoundDir/sonar-beep.wav` appropriately.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am having the same issue with my Image Files.  I edited my original post to reflect this.  I posted the code.  Could you review it to see what is wrong?  Thanks so much!